# xml parsing from android device storage

Tags: android, xml, apk

I am new to android and I want to parse xml file from specific path in device storage and insert the data into several lists . The tags are also valid in xml . There is file in the mentioned path and I have checked it . but I get errors on that . can anyone help me please ?

```
    List<String> query = new ArrayList<String);
    List<String> option11 = new ArrayList<String);
    List<String> option22 = new ArrayList<String);
    List<String> option33 = new ArrayList<String);
    List<String> option44 = new ArrayList<String);
    List<String> answer1 = new ArrayList<String);
//file3 is the name of xml file 
    try {
        File datafile3 = null;
        File rootpath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "exam");
        datafile3 = new File(rootpath, file3);

        String question, option1, option2, option3, option4, answer;

        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream mmm = new FileInputStream(datafile3);
        doc = dBuilder.parse(mmm);
        Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
        element.normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("question");


        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element2 = (Element) node;
                question = getValue("questiontext", element2);
                option1 = getValue("option1", element2);
                option2 = getValue("option2", element2);
                option3 = getValue("option3", element2);
                option4 = getValue("option4", element);
                answer = getValue("answer", element2);
                query.add(question);
                option11.add(option1);
                option22.add(option2);
                option22.add(option3);
                option22.add(option4);
                answer1.add(answer);

            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {

    }
```